# REGEX: Select matches in between two slashes?

Tags: python, regex

I want to select words that have slashes in between them, so not just slashes alone.

I'm using this code: `(/.+?/)`, but that doesn't work

Full string:

```
COOL /RE/
COOL RE
/
```

I'm trying to get word from first line only. `/RE/`

Comment: / = slash, \ = backslash.Which one do you mean?

Comment: What do you actually want to match from the first line?   The entire line or only some part of it?

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen Only `/RE/`

Comment: @some my bad, I meant slash

Comment: You need to say what environment you're in. Regex syntax differs by language and/or library.

Comment: @Gene It's python

Comment: What would be the expected match for `/RE/TEST/` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe,

```
/\S+/
```

might simply work.

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/zKZylg/1/)

Comment: `\S` captures puctuation and numbers -- not sure OP wants that

Answer (score 2):

Since you mentioned you want "words", I think the pattern would be

`/\w+/`

If you wanted to only capture the word between the forward slashes, use a capture group:

`/(\w+)/`